# Attach Linked List to a Vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

I was looking into separate chaining using hash_map and that is kind of what I need but not entirely. A hash_map will automatically delete duplicate values even in a chain. I dont want that.

Consider I have a vector of size 4. I want to basically attach a linked list to each one of the indexes of the vector. the linked list can have duplicate elements as well.

I researched about this but could not find a STL for this. Is there a way to do this?

I want to do this to create a database table. I have a vector of size 4. The 4 spots are columns in the table and the linked list attached to each index are the rows for the table. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please organize your thoughts before you post. Put some spaces between your sentences, it is considered to be a great sentiment.

Comment: Are you after a [multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) instead?

Comment: A vector or vectors or vector of lists?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
std::vector<std::list<std::string> > > myweirdlist;
```

Then you can add more lists to `myweirdlist`. And `myweirdlist[0]` for example will be a linked list which you can operate one.

Comment: wow....thanks for the reply guys....amazing. Ok so all the data is strings. I did look into map and it seemed like it might be a fit but wasnt sure. so you are saying something like this would work? vector<list> myweirdlist; but then whats the datatype for this? I need it to hold strings. how do I insert data into this list? does it work like this? 
`code
myweirdlist[0]->hi->hello->yes->bye
myweirdlist[1]->Jorge->2to1mux->Peter 
`
....and so on...cause thats kind of what i want
Sorry for the formatting....how do you add code tags?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want a Vector of Lists. Please specify the type for the data that you want to store in your table. The declaration will depend on that... If you're storing ints, it would look like this:

```
std::vector<std::list<int> > vecOfLists;
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the row in a class. Store a vector of objects of that class.

If you have a lot of deletions as well as insertions, maybe a `list` would be better, instead of the `vector`.

```
struct MyRecord {
    // fields
};

std::vector<MyRecord> myRecordTable;
```